# Doing base64 decoding on a string in Go

Tags: string, go, base64

I have a particular string that I need to run base64 decode on in Go. This string looks something like this:

`qU4aaakFmjaaaaI5aaa\/EN\/aaa\/SaaaJaaa6aa+nGnk=`

Please note this is not the exact same string but it does have the same shape and number of characters, padding characters and it has those `\/` things on the same positions in the string.

Let's call it key.

In PHP if I run

`base64_decode($key);`

the decode operation is successful

If In Python I run

`base64.b64decode(key)`

the decode operation is once more successful. Problem is, I can't do base64 decoding on this thing in Go.

```
dcd, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("qU4aaakFmjaaaaI5aaa\\/EN\\/aaa\\/SaaaJaaa6aa+nGnk=")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
return dcd
```

This will return the error

```
illegal base64 data at input byte 19
```

In the Go version, I have to escape those backslashes. It seems that the error appears at byte 19. Bearing in mind that this string that I am using as an example has the same length as the string that is actually causing the problem I would believe that the error happens right at the byte with the \ character. What can I do about this?

Comment: The alphabet of the standard Base64 does not contain backslash. So the `qU4aaakFmjaaaaI5aaa\/EN\/aaa\/SaaaJaaa6aa+nGnk=` input is not valid Base64 encoded string. What do you expect? How other languages skip or omit this error does not apply to Go.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to just get it to work? I am using this string with those 2 other languages and it is impossible to change it. I tried removing the \ / characters, ended up getting an error on byte 40 (which now contained "=" ). Removed that one too but the it gave errors for byte 0.

Comment: The forward slash is valid character in Base64, just not the backslash. It's possible the `\/` is a sequence designating a single slash. If so, replace the `\/` sequences with a single `/` and you're good to go.

Comment: Removing the backslashes leaves me with ```qU4aaakFmjaaaaI5aaa/EN/aaa/SaaaJaaa6aa+nGnk=``` but this also returns an error: ```illegal base64 data at input byte 0```

Comment: Removing the backslashes results in a valid Base64 input, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SGdzqEbqNO2).

Comment: Thanks! This worked but I was probably doing something wrong when re-running my program locally. If you would care to add this as an answer I would select it as the appropriate one.

Comment: I also added a solution how to omit all invalid characters from the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alphabet of the standard Base64 does not contain backslash. So the `qU4aaakFmjaaaaI5aaa\/EN\/aaa\/SaaaJaaa6aa+nGnk=` input is not valid Base64 encoded string.

The forward slash is valid character in Base64, just not the backslash. It's possible the `\/` is a sequence designating a single slash. If so, replace the `\/` sequences with a single `/` and you're good to go.

For example:

```
s := `qU4aaakFmjaaaaI5aaa\/EN\/aaa\/SaaaJaaa6aa+nGnk=`
s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, `\/`, `/`)
dcd, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(dcd))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/INOx1vCHUZ_I)):

```
�Ni��6�i�9i����i��i��i��i��y
```

If `\/` is not a special sequence and you want to discard all invalid characters from the input, this is how it could be done:

```
var valid = map[rune]bool{}

func init() {
    for _, r := range "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=" {
        valid[r] = true
    }
}

func clean(s string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if valid[r] {
            return r
        }
        return -1
    }, s)
}

func main() {
    s := `qU4aaakFmjaaaaI5aaa\/EN\/aaa\/SaaaJaaa6aa+nGnk=`
    s = clean(s)
    dcd, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(dcd))
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6E1GpjiBSzH).